# use boto3 session when opening s3 url

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, smart-open

I see a lot of code that uses an S3 bucket url to open a file. I would like to use smart open to open a compressed file

```
session = boto3.Session(ID, pass)
file = open("s3://bucket/file.txt.gz", transport_params=dict(session=session), encoding="utf-8")
```

However, all the examples I see about smart open and other pulls from boto3 using a url never specify how to use the session when pulling the data from the url only when pushing data to a new bucket. Is there a way to use the url and the session without needing to create a client from my session and access the bucket and key?

Comment: Does the [example from the documentation](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/blob/develop/README.rst#more-examples) cover this?

Comment: No, this is what I was looking at when I wrote the question. They use the session always to write to a bucket, but they just use a public url I think when pulling from a bucket. Unless I'm mistaken

Comment: The example is showing how to use `open`, if you want to open a file for reading, change the `wb` to `rb` in it.

Comment: If you try and hit the s3 url with open, and it isn't public, you will get an access denied or doesn't exist error.

Comment: That's why you need to pass in `client` like in the example.

Comment: Yup you are right. I must have not put in the url right or something the first time I tried that, because it works now

Comment: You can list that as the answer if you'd like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you just need to replace "wb" with "rb". I was mistaken that this didn't work

```
from smart_open import open
import boto3

url = 's3://bucket/your/keyz'
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id,
                        aws_secret_access_key,
                        region_name)

with open(url, 'rb', transport_params={'client': session.client('s3')}) as fin:
    file = fin.read()

print(file)
```